# JQuery, find parent

Tags: jquery, parent

```
<ul><li><div><div><span id="thisid"></span></div></div></li></ul>

$('#thisid').parent('li');
```

that obviously doesn't work, but how do I grab the li element? I don't want to use:

```
$('#this').parent().parent().parent();
```

I don't want to use it, because it can happen that there is just one div element, instead of two. In this case I would grab the ul element instead of the li element.

Answer (score 99, accepted):

```
$('#thisid').parents('li');
//                 ^ plural!
```

Note that if you only want the first `<li>` element in the ancestry, you should use `closest()`:

```
$('#thisid').closest('li');

// `closest()` is equivalent to (but performs better than)
$('#thisid').parents('li').eq(0);
$('#thisid').parents('li').first();
```

- http://api.jquery.com/closest/
- http://api.jquery.com/parents/

Comment: All four examples are great solutions.

Comment: Just wanted to make it clear that singular "parent()" *is* a valid function call;  it just doesn't do what the question-asker was needing.

Comment: This solution works like a charm, just want to point a caveat: `.closest()` also checks the actual element from which it is called: If the element has the same selector as the requested parent, it won't work. You need to use `.parents()` in such case. For me, `.parents('someSelector').eq(0)` worked out just fine.

Answer (score 7):

```
$('#thisid').parents('li')
```

or if you only want the first one:

```
$('#thisid').closest('li')
```

Answer (score 3):

```
$('li').has('#thisid')
```

http://api.jquery.com/has/

Comment: interesting alternative, although potentially a lot slower

Answer (score 2):

Simple, use [`parents()`](http://api.jquery.com/parents/)

```
var parents = $("#thisid").parents('li');
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$('#thisid').parents( 'li:eq(0)' );
```

Should do it. This will give you the first (`:eq(0)`) parent that matches being the tag you're searching for.

Answer (score 1):

I prefer the 'closest' than 'parents'.

Parents travel up the DOM tree to the document's root element, adding each ancestor element to a temporary collection; it then filters that collection based on a selector if one is supplied.

where

Closest Travel up the DOM tree until it finds a match for the supplied selector.

Most important what they give in result:

Praents: Returned jQuery object contains zero or more elements for each element in the original set, in reverse document order.

Closest: Returned jQuery object contains zero or one element for each element in the original set, in document order

```
$('#thisid').closest('li');
```

[Follow this Link](http://api.jquery.com/closest/#closest1)

Answer (score 0):

You may actually want to use `$("#thisid").closest('li')`. This traverses up the DOM tree from the selected node and returns the first matching ancestor whereas the `.parents()` travels from the parent node and returns all ancestor nodes matching that filter. See [here](http://api.jquery.com/closest/) for more information.