# Find the parent value?

Tags: jquery, onclick, parent

I need an onclick event so that all 4 <input> will read the id value of the row: "2013-0455".

In my head, I see each *input* as a *child* of the *tr* in JQuery. I don't know how to make it happen?

If that does not work, I want to be able to click on any of the 4 *inputs* and get the value of `id="File_Number"`

```
<tr id="2013-0455">
<td><input id="File_Number" value="2013-0455" type="readonly" size="7"></td>
<td><input id="File_DateTime" value="2013-03-16 03:08:12" type="readonly" size="18"></td>
<td><input id="Address" value="123 Sesame Street" type="readonly" size="20"></td>
<td><input id="File_Comments" value="Something said done entered" type="readonly" size="30"></td>
</tr>
```

Comment: jquery closest might work, but cannot find an example through Google

Comment: possible duplicate of [JQuery, find parent](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4718409/jquery-find-parent)

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$('input').click(function() {
  var id = $(this).parents('tr').attr('id');
});
```

Comment: jquery is magic. I've only discovered it recdntly, that's how much coding I do these days. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you want?

```
$('input').click(function () {
    var x = $(this).closest('tr').attr('id');
    console.log(x);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try the following:

```
$('input').click(function() {
  var value = $("#File_Number").val();
});
```

Let me know if that works for you.